# Get Array from JSON encode via AJAX

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to get 4 JSON arrays that I have in a separate file into my main file using AJAX request. For reason, I can't seem to get the arrays into variables and to display it in console log.
This is the results from the JSON file:

```
[[5,10,10.99,10.99,13,5,14.31,1,1,5,5,5,1,5,3,3,5,5,1,5,10.32,10.32,5,8,5,10,5,5,19,5,7.36,7.36,5,12.2,12.2,2.2,2.2,23.3,5,10.87,6.87,6.87,5,5,10,10,10,10,5,5,5,5,5,0,5,5],

[8,12.5,12.5,12.53,12.53,8,10.11,1,1,8,8,8,1,8,3,3,8,8,1,8,12.83,32.32,8,8,8,10,8.31,8,10,8,18.2,18.2,8,10.3,10.3,2.29,2.29,12.3,8,8.23,2.23,2.23,8,8,10,10,10,20,5,5,5,5,8,0,8,2],

[6,8.86,8.86,8.87,8.87,6,8.33,1,2,6,2,3,1,6,3,8,6,6,1,6,8.32,7.32,6,8,6,10,3.31,6,12,6,12.3,12.3,6,11.1,11.1,4.09,4.09,33.1,6,5.16,12.16,2.16,6,6,10,20,30,30,30,30,5,0,6,0,6,5],

[19,31.36,32.36,32.4,34.4,19,32.76,3,4,19,15,16,3,19,9,14,19,19,3,19,31.47,49.96,19,24,19,30,16.62,19,41,19,37.86,37.86,19,33.6,33.6,8.6,8.6,68.7,19,24.26,21.26,11.26,19,19,30,40,50,60,40,40,15,10,19,0,19,12]]
```

This is how I tried to get it into my main page:

```
function callback(response) {
      var array1 = response[0];
      var array2 = response[1];
      var array3 = response[2];
      var array4 = response[3];
      console.log(array1);
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'loadchart.php',
  success: callback
});
```

The result that I get from trying to get only the all the array1 is only a bracket:

```
[
```

Code from loadchart.php:

```
<?php 

  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['usersId']))
  {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
  }
  else
  {
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
  }

  $id = $_SESSION['userId']; 
  $dBname = "infosensor";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBname);

  $sql = "SELECT sensor1, sensor2, sensor3 FROM `$id`;";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $jsonsensor1 = array();
  $jsonsensor2 = array();
  $jsonsensor3 = array();
  $jsonsensorsum = array();
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      $jsonsensor1[] = intval($row['sensor1'] * ($p = pow(10, 2))) / $p;
      $jsonsensor2[] = intval($row['sensor2'] * ($p = pow(10, 2))) / $p;
      $jsonsensor3[] = intval($row['sensor3'] * ($p = pow(10, 2))) / $p;
      $jsonsensorsum[] = intval(($row['sensor1'] + $row['sensor2'] + $row['sensor3']) * ($p = pow(10, 2))) / $p;
      $data = [$jsonsensor1,$jsonsensor2,$jsonsensor3,$jsonsensorsum];
    } 
  }

  echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Will you share the code of `loadchart.php`?

Comment: sure, I will edit real quick

Comment: @pindev there you go :)

Comment: Did you check `network` panel of browser developer tools to check whether the API returns correct data?

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: `https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network`, you could see here how to do it

Comment: @pindev Ow, yes. When outputting the data, without trying to select the array It will give me all the array. And it appear at my network

Comment: @pindev This is what I get from the network: 0: [5, 10, 10.99, 10.99, 13, 5, 14.31, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 1, 5, 10.32, 10.32, 5, 8, 5, 10,…]
1: [8, 12.5, 12.5, 12.53, 12.53, 8, 10.11, 1, 1, 8, 8, 8, 1, 8, 3, 3, 8, 8, 1, 8, 12.83, 32.32, 8, 8, 8,…]
2: [6, 8.86, 8.86, 8.87, 8.87, 6, 8.33, 1, 2, 6, 2, 3, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 6, 1, 6, 8.32, 7.32, 6, 8, 6, 10,…]
3: [19, 31.36, 32.36, 32.4, 34.4, 19, 32.76, 3, 4, 19, 15, 16, 3, 19, 9, 14, 19, 19, 3, 19, 31.47, 49.96,…]

Comment: I think it returns as string, Try to `String.stringify(response)` before you do `var array1 = response[0];`

Comment: @pindev I accidentally found out hahaha, It is because in the ajax request I didn't put dataType as json, Thank you for your time thought. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add dataType as json:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'loadchart.php',
      dataType:"json",
      success: callback
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do one thing user JSON.parse to parse your json array 
like i have done in your function

```
function callback(response) {
  var res= JSON.parse(response);
  var array1 = res[0];
  var array2 = res[1];
  var array3 = res[2];
  var array4 = res[3];
  console.log(array1);
}
```